# How do I mock HostingEnvironment properly when unit testing?

Tags: c#, moq

I am trying to test a code block that says.

```
if (!HostingEnvironment.IsHosted) 
{
    throw new Exception();
} 
else 
{
    doWork();
}
```

I've been trying to create a new instance like this

```
var hostEnv = new HostingEnvironment();
```

It works when each test is ran individually but sometimes throws exceptions with the message

> "there can only be one HostingEnvironment in an AppDomain."

Comment: WebForms cannot be tested like this - it's one of the reasons why WebForms is dead now. Instead, refactor your business/domain logic _out_ to a new class-library with no dependencies on `System.Web.dll` and define your own interfaces that hide `HttpContext`, `HttpRequest`, etc - and _then_ you can test it.

Comment: If you use ASP.NET *Core*, `app.Environment` is an interface registered in the DI container. This means it can easily be mocked just by using a dummy implementation. You can specify an environment with `UseEnvironment` either in the host configuration or when using a [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#customize-webapplicationfactory) for integration tests

Comment: Is this [HostingEnvironment.IsHosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.ishosted)? If so, it's `static` and non-virtual, so can't be replaced by a Test Double (i.e. can't be 'mocked').

Comment: if you really want to mock that check, you can simply wrap the logic by an instance by create a class called e.g. HostingEnvInfoProvider with a function of isHosted.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Unless you wanna get cozy with `Detours`

Comment: Thank you @Dai I think refactoring is the way.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSeemann